# How can I ignore th:text in thymeleaf

Tags: java, frontend, thymeleaf

We want to create a project for frontend use of thymeleaf without eclipse.
We need to process thymeleft in order to use fragments, th:insert, th:replace etc.

The frontend needs layout creation but doesn't need variables replaces.
We don't want th:text because it needs creating a lot of variables unnecessary.

Can we ignore only th:text and run other thymeleaf dialects?

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: If you don't want to use **th:text** don't put it in your code Or use it inside **th:if** condition to run in certain conditions only.

Comment: the frontend guy want run a jar but cant replace th:text objects. inside eclipse the th:text will run normally. it is too easely the frontend work.